# Hololens - stream microphone to PC

Tags: c#, naudio, microphone, hololens

I would like to send, in real time, the microphone stream of the Hololens (first generation) to a PC. I am using the MicrophoneTransmitter.cs from the VoiceChat example, that I modified to send the stream using a UDP socket. On the PC side, I use NAudio to hear it. The NAudio receiver is set at 48000 Hz, 32 bits, 1 channel (I retrieved these information from MicrophoneTransmitter.cs).
The communication works and I receive the packets on the PC. However, there is a lot of (what looks like) background noise. There is no such noise when I stream the microphones over the web portal of the Hololens. It also slows down the Hololens app.
I am not familiar with audio processing. 
Is there someone who already did something similar?

Comment: If you record the same audio stream on the device and compare the recording vs the streamed content do you hear the same noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC supports sending audio and video streams over a network between HoloLens and PCs. You might be able to leverage the [MixedReality-WebRTC codebase](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC). It supports some echo cancellation, noise reduction, etc.